# Cron job not working in Raspberry

Tags: php, linux, cron, raspberry-pi

I want to add a cron job in my Raspberry to execute a task every five minutes.
So I do in the terminal:

```
crontab -e
```

and then add at the file:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php myscript path.
```

The script is something very simple. just to try if it works:

```
 <?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A") . "<br>";;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

The problem is that the date isn't updated, so the cron job doesn't work. Any idea of the problem ?

**UPDATE**

This what I got, when I execute crobtab -e

```
    GNU nano 2.2.6        File: /tmp/crontab.3IXg0z/crontab                       

# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /full/path/myscript.php
```

Comment: are you SURE it doesn't work? check your account's mail. cron emails output/job logs to the account.plus `.../php myscript path` implies that your php code file is called `myscript`, and you're passing in `path` as a command-line argument.

Comment: Can you go through the debugging steps on the [crontab tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) and report your findings?

Comment: The script has 777 permission, as the file. The full line, I have added is: */5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html/test.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure the script is executable:

```
chmod +x /path/to/some/script.php
```

Second, make sure your script has an appropriate `#!` (or *"shebang"*) on the very first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

Then make sure your cron job is configured correctly. The format for cron is typically `m h dom mon dow command`

```
sudo crontab -e

*/5 * * * * /path/to/some/script.php
```

Comment: I have already set executable. If executed this command in the terminal it works the script.php: /usr/bin/php /path/test.php. I think in the crontab -e, you have to insert the php path of the machine

Comment: does the script have `#!/usr/bin/php` in the first line? If it does, you do not need to call `/usr/bin/php`

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to run a script every 5 minutes you should add this entry.

`*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /full/path/to/php/script.php`

Comment: That is what I wrote: */5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html/test.php, but nothing happens !

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `PATH` variable set correctly on crontab, so it can locate your file.

You can simple put following line in top of `crontab`

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/path/to/newfile.txt
```

Try, following test

```
* * * * * touch /tmp/hello
```

Do following  to redirect result

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /full/path/to/php/script.php > /tmp/out.txt
```

Make sure your script running on command line.

```
/usr/bin/php /full/path/to/php/script.php
```

Use the -f option to execute the script:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /full/path/to/php/script.php
```

Tail logs file to see its executing every 5 min

```
tail -f /var/log/cron
```

Comment: I modify the question, so you can have a look at my file.

Comment: Does your script executing on shell `/usr/bin/php /full/path/myscript.php` ?

Comment: yes, it works great that line, but not with crobtab :(

Comment: Lets try hello world program and see how it goes  `<?php  Print "Hello, World!\n"; ?>`  and put that in your crontab `* * * * * /usr/bin/php /tmp/helloworld.php >> /tmp/helloworld.out`

Comment: also try this `*/5 * * * * php /full/path/myscript.php`  don't use `/usr/bin/php` and put `#!/usr/bin/env php` in your script, sounds odd but i have seen this issue before in perl

Comment: I don't why, but I made your test and it works everything, also with my script ! Thank you so much ! By the way, I don't know what could happen !